# How can I query data from contract storage?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, get-storage-at

If I have a contract like below:

`contract wallet{`

```
   mapping (address => uint) balances
   function send(){...}
   ......
```

`}`

and I deploy this contract on the ethereum.

When I want to query the **balances** for example check the balance of Alice, is there any api to do this query directly like SQL.

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/web3-eth-getstorageat-for-mapping  and [tag:get-storage-at]

Answer (score 1):

There is no query api like SQL, you can invoke contract method to finish it. This is a simple contract, you can get balance by name

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Wallet {

    mapping (address => uint) balance;

    function desosite() payable{
        balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getBlance() constant returns (uint) {
        return balance[msg.sender];
    }


}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Can  I call the "getbalance()" to get data outside the etherum? Or it can only be called by another contract?

Comment: If you had deployed this contract on private chain, call `your_contract_name.getBalance(from:eth.coinbase)`