# What tools exist for reading non-public storage?

Tags: evm

What tools or methods exist for querying arbitrary contract storage?

The problem at hand is having to inspect smart contract state variables that have been marked as internal. Block explorers, Remix, and other tools only make it easy to query public state.

Comment: Have a look at this post as well: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/web3-eth-getstorageat-for-mapping/64342

Comment: Crazy how difficult this still is to do https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2373#discussioncomment-3600149

Answer (score 2):

You can open truffle console connected to a public node if you want. Then you can use the api call `web3.eth.getStorage(address, slot)` to get the data at individual storage slots. I don't know of any tool you can easily plug a smart contract and have it tell you want slot each variable is at, but generally the state variables are in order by declaration. It'll likely vary slightly though.

Answer (score 0):

With [0xweb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/0xweb) tool you can install validated contracts locally; one feature is to list and read all variables.

```sh
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb i 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48 --name USDC --chain eth
$ 0xweb c vars USDC --chain eth
$ 0xweb c var USDC _owner --chain eth
```

> It lists and also reads private variables.

You can also save all state variables of the contract:

```sh
0xweb c dump USDC --chain eth
```

> Public nodes are used, that have rate-limits, you should add your rpc node for eth with `0xweb config -e`